# How to solve parameters given 3 different types of information?

Tags: diophantine-equations

How Do I solve this eqns?

$$x+y+z = A$$
$$xyz = B$$
$$x^2+y^2+z^2 = C$$

I have tried it in this way,,,

$$yz = B/x = P$$
$$y+z = A-x = Q$$
$$y(Q-y) = P$$
$$\implies y^2-Qy+p = 0$$

I can't figure out what to do next., Solving the this quadratic equation for y and z and putting the values in 3, doesnt seem to work. cause there will be sqrt in the eqn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have 
$$xy+yz+zx=\frac{1}{2}((x+y+z)^2-x^2-y^2-z^2)=\frac{1}{2}(A^2-C)=C'$$
so by [Vieta's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) $x,y$ and $z$ are solutions of the polynomial equation:
$$t^3-At^2+C't-B=0$$

Comment: :( Is there any way to better the guess of one root in cubic equation?

Comment: In the case where the coefficients $A,B$ and $C$ are integers we can use the rational root theorem to find a possible rational root.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $xy + yz + zx = (x+y+z)^2 - (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) = \frac{A^2 - C}{2}$

Consider the equation $M^3 - AM^2 + ( \frac{A^2-C} {2} )M - B=0$. It has roots $x, y$ and $ z$.